# AsyncTask with Glide for clearing Cache

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-glide

It is throwing an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on the main thread

Code:

```
Class CacheClearAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Glide.get(getActivity()).clearDiskCache();
        Glide.get(getActivity()).clearMemory();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Void result)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cache cleared", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Setting preference on click event:

```
clearCacheBtnPref=findPreference(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_btn_clear_cache_key));
    clearCacheBtnPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new 

Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    new CacheClearAsyncTask().execute();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

This can not be called in main thread as it is also throws errors and also it does not let me use asynctask.

```
    Glide.get(getActivity()).clearDiskCache();
    Glide.get(getActivity()).clearMemory();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glide assert: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on the main thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658806/glide-assert-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-you-must-call-this-method-on-t)

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: @lelloman i want clear all the cache files on button click

Comment: "_You must call this method on the main thread_"

Comment: @lelloman it does not work if i put it in main thread.it shows `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: YOu must call this method on a background thread`

Comment: It is confusing.

Comment: confusing it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clearDiskCache()` must be called from background thread while `clearMemory()` from main thread so:

```
class CacheClearAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Glide.get(getActivity()).clearDiskCache();    
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Void result)    {
        Glide.get(getActivity()).clearMemory();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your use case or app flow. But `doInBackground` is specifically used to do operations in background thread than Main UI thread.

Now if you need to do changes corresponding to Main UI thread in `doInBackground` , then do as following

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {

                            Glide.get(getActivity()).clearDiskCache();
                            Glide.get(getActivity()).clearMemory();
                       }
                   });

        return null;
    }
```

For more examples on `runOnUiThread`  [refer this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=android.app.Activity&method=runOnUiThread)

Comment: No, you should put it in onPostExecute or onPreExecute

Comment: Yah I agree. onPostExecute is specifically for performing in UI thread. But what if this guy needs to perform something in a loop basis and on doInbackground which will update the UI thread? That is the first sentence of my answer... that I dont know his use case or app flow. But if he really wants to update UI in doInBackground, then the solution will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Both method works in different thread.

clearDiskCache() must be called on a background thread.
clearMemory() must be called on the main thread.
You can't call both at once on the same thread.

```
void clearGlideCache()
{
    new Thread() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Glide.get(DemoActivity.this).clearDiskCache();
        }
    }.start();

    Glide.get(DemoActivity.this).clearMemory();
}
```