# Glide sometime not working but sometime it works

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using Glide v4 and it is not always can get bitmap from Url. Sometimes it works and Sometimes it does not work and throw an exception. I don't know why. this is the Exception:`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on a background thread`  and this is my code:

```
            try {
                bitmap=Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext())
                        .asBitmap().load(icon).fitCenter()
                        .circleCrop().submit().get();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_default_user_image);
            }
```

I am facing another problem with Glide, this is the issue I made on Glide Github  : https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3590

Comment: Error is pretty clear: you cannot call glide on the main thread, you need to make it in the background.

Comment: but sometime it works. That is the problem, I dont know how can it work

Comment: It's hard to tell without context, maybe you sometimes call it from asynctask.

Comment: No, I dont use Async. but let me try Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says - "You must call this method on a background thread", for example :

```
Thread mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    try  {
    //Put your code that you want to run in here
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});

mThread.start
```

Comment: but sometime it works , I dont know why. I will try and let you know if it works

Comment: Maybe you load local data sometimes (no network is done on the main thread so no exception) and some other time you load data from the internet (there is networking on the main thread and you are getting the exeption)

Comment: sure, glad to help

Comment: I have another problem with Glide. I updated my question

Comment: Check [this](http://www.gadgetsaint.com/android/circular-images-glide-library-android/#.XKIZzZhvaUk), this may help you

Comment: the problem is about the quality of image. I dont know how to fix, I followed the thread, Many dev have the same problem and they fix it by using that code but for me , it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on a background thread**

The exception is very clear . you can't run your code that load a img on the main thread(which is UI Thread).  This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658806/glide-assert-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-you-must-call-this-method-on-t) may solve ur problem.